# value not ignored "(argaddr(0, &fva)"

Tags: c, arguments, void, xv6

I am looking to add xv6 page table functionality. However, for some reason I am getting errors with `argaddr` and `argint`. Why?

Lab reference: [xv6 page table](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2022/labs/pgtbl.html)

```
int sys_pgaccess(void){
  uint64 fva;
  int pnum;
  uint64 abits;
  int res = 0;
  pte_t* pte_addr;
  pte_t pte;


  if(argaddr(0, &fva) < 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  if(argint(1, &pnum) < 0) {
    return -1;
  }
```

```
kernel/sysproc.c: In function 'sys_pgaccess':
kernel/sysproc.c:105:6: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  105 |   if(argaddr(0, &fva) < 0) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kernel/sysproc.c:108:6: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  108 |   if(argint(1, &pnum) < 0) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am a beginner so I looked at the code for `argaddr`, etc., but could not understand it.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that these functions return a value `<0` in case of error? Did you find any manual for these functions indicating that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that `argaddr` and `argint` are *void* functions, and do not return a value.

You cannot compare *nothing* with an integer.

Looking at [*kernel/syscall.c*](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/kernel/syscall.c) from [mit-pdos/xv6-riscv](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/), we can see the RISC-V function definitions:

```
// Fetch the nth 32-bit system call argument.
void
argint(int n, int *ip)
{
  *ip = argraw(n);
}

// Retrieve an argument as a pointer.
// Doesn't check for legality, since
// copyin/copyout will do that.
void
argaddr(int n, uint64 *ip)
{
  *ip = argraw(n);
}
```

The contents of the lab linked deal with RISC-V.

It appears you should simply remove the conditionals:

```
int sys_pgaccess(void)
{
  uint64 fva;
  int pnum;
  /* ... */
 
  argaddr(0, &fva);
  argint(1, &pnum);
  /* ... */
}
```

---

For completeness, the x86 versions of these functions do return values, so you may have read the wrong documentation.

[*syscall.c*](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/syscall.c) from the no longer maintained [mit-pdos/xv6-public](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public) contains the x86 definitions:

```
// Fetch the int at addr from the current process.
int
fetchint(uint addr, int *ip)
{
  struct proc *curproc = myproc();

  if(addr >= curproc->sz || addr+4 > curproc->sz)
    return -1;
  *ip = *(int*)(addr);
  return 0;
}

// Fetch the nth 32-bit system call argument.
int
argint(int n, int *ip)
{
  return fetchint((myproc()->tf->esp) + 4 + 4*n, ip);
}

// Fetch the nth word-sized system call argument as a pointer
// to a block of memory of size bytes.  Check that the pointer
// lies within the process address space.
int
argptr(int n, char **pp, int size)
{
  int i;
  struct proc *curproc = myproc();
 
  if(argint(n, &i) < 0)
    return -1;
  if(size < 0 || (uint)i >= curproc->sz || (uint)i+size > curproc->sz)
    return -1;
  *pp = (char*)i;
  return 0;
}
```